# Classroom Scheduling Using Graph Algorithm

Tags: graph, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search, bipartite

This is another question from my past midterm, and i am supposed to give a formal formulation, describe the algorithm used, and justify the correctness. Here is the problem:

The University is trying to schedule *n* different classes. Each class has a start and finish time. All classes have to be taught on Friday. There are only two classrooms available.

Help the university decide whether it is possible to schedule these classes without causing any time conflict (i.e. two classes with overlapping class times are scheduled in the same classroom).

Comment: So we're supposed to help you cheat on your midterm?

Comment: @Gene no, the midterm happened already. I can't answer this question, and I want to know how to solve this problem to prepare myself for later.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the classes by starting time (O(nlogn)), then go through them in order (O(n)), noting starting and ending times and looking for the case of more than two classes going on at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem with a bipartite graph solution. Who told you it was?

@Beta is nearly correct.  Create a list of pairs `<START, time>` and `<END, time>`. Each class has two pairs in the list, one START, and one END.

Now sort the list by time. Or if you like, put them in a min heap, which amounts to heapsort. For equal times, put the END triples before START. Then execute the following loop:

```
set N = 0
while sorted list not empty
  pop <tag, time> from the head of the list
  if tag == START
    N = N + 1
    if N > 2 return "can't schedule"
  else // tag == END
    N = N - 1
  end
end
return "can schedule"
```

You can easily enrich the algorithm a bit to return the time periods where more than 2 classes are in session at the same time, return those classes, and other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

This indeed IS a bipartite/bicoloring problem.

Imagine each class to be a node of a graph. Now create an edge between 2 nodes if they have time overlap. Now the final graph that you get if you can bicolor this graph then its possible to schedule all the class. Otherwise not.

The graph you created if it can be bicolored, then each "black" node will belong to room1 and each "white" node will belong to room2